# How can I test if a directory exists, and create a Path object with one line of code?

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm new to using the Python `pathlib` library, so please edit this question if I'm using incorrect terminology here and there...

I'm using the `Path` class to both create a directory if it doesn't exist, and then to instantiate a `Path` object.  I currently have this as two lines of code like this because the `mkdir` method returns `NoneType`:

```py
my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir").mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir")
```

Is there a way to do this with one line of code?  Should I be taking a completely different approach?

Comment: May I ask *why* you feel this is necessary? Why not just `my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir")` to create the `Path` object, followed by `my_path..mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)` to use it (better than your current duplicated code approach)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Readability counts](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/). Reducing the number of lines of code should not be a goal in and of itself. Rather, it should be a *side effect* of simplifications that are *beneficial for different reasons* (e.g. removing repetition, reducing complexity, emphasizing symmetry, etc.).

I would recommend leaving this as two lines as

```
my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir")
my_path.mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
```

But if you really want to write this as one line, you could use either of the following

```
(my_path := Path("my_dir/my_subdir")).mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)


my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir"); my_path.mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
```

or you could define a function that ensures that the directory exists when the `Path` is created:

```
def path_mkdir(s: str | bytes | os.PathLike) -> Path:
    path = Path(s)
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return path


my_path = path_mkdir("my_dir/my_subdir")
```

Comment: I'm completely blind. Posted an answer duplicating the walrus solution, thinking this was only covering "Don't do it" or "wrap in a function". Blech. Deleted my own answer, have an up-vote for saying literally everything I came here to say!

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, to create a directory and do Path object instantiation in a single line, you can use the following code:

```
my_path = Path("my_dir/my_subdir").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) or Path("my_dir/my_subdir")
```

In this line, Path("my_dir/my_subdir").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) is gonna try to create the directory. If the directory already exists, it returns None, but we use the or operator to fall back to Path("my_dir/my_subdir") to instantiate a Path object.
I think doing that will allow you to combine both actions into 1 line

Comment: Although this works,it's less readable. And readability counts, you know... It's the same code,, just on one line. Only marginally better than combining the 2 lines with using semi-colon

Comment: Well, he could maintain the 2 liner code for readability reasons

Comment: Or why not encapsulate the directory creation logic into a small function, then use it

Comment: What an abomination.

Comment: It's not just less readable, it's more error-prone. If you change one literal path, but not the other, now it's creating one directory, but you'll try to use a different one. I'm not religiously against a *little* bit of conciseness at the expense of the ideal style; the walrus isn't great, but it's not the worst. This is the worst. It's brittle too, *relying* on `mkdir` not returning anything useful. If, at some point in the future, they decide to make the `exist_ok` version of the call return `True` to indicate the directory had to be created, `False` otherwise, well now your code is broken.

Comment: You make much sense

Comment: Yeah, I should make a function, and keep it two lines of code.  That's the way.